# Median poker hand (Texas Hold’em)

Tags: binomial-coefficients, median, poker

I try to find the median poker hand (Texas Hold’em). The following is given:

1) There are [52 cards](http://www.eypo-bet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/poker.cards_.png)

2) Assuming seven of them are chosen randomly

3) Create the best possibility with 5 of these 7 cards (see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands))

Probably it could be done by by just generating all $nCr(52,7)$ card combinations, get always the best poker hand and order all these results. Unfortunately this does not seem to be very easy.

Maybe there is a math trick to simplify this or someone just know the answer (e.g. 5♥ 5♣ 4♦ 3♠ 3♣)?

Thank you very much

Comment: I do not think that there is a shortcut. But using the probabilities, it should be possible to determine what kind of result the median hand is (for example : one pair)

Comment: $C(52,7)$ is more than 132 million.  But if you really wanted to follow a brute-force approach, look for libraries out there like https://github.com/worldveil/deuces (found this by googling "python poker library")

Comment: There is nearly a 50% chance of getting a pair.  Since there is a 17% chance of no pair.  I am comming up with a pair of 10's as median (not sure of the kicker.)

Comment: Why is there a 50% chance to get a pair? Unfortunately i cannot use the probabilities from "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands", because they also count hands like "2♥ 3♣ 4♦ 5♠ 7♣" as high card. But this combination is not possible in the way i described (this is never the best combination with 5 cards given 7 cards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [list for best 5 from 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) one pair starts at 38.8% and ends at 82.6%.
So using liner interpolation QQ is the median hand.